# Problems with base HTML tag in QWebView

Tags: html, qt

I'm using base HTML tag in my page to obtain relative links to css files.

```
  <base href="d:/Server/styles/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webflow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/help-template-1.webflow.css">
```

Chrome browser understands this perfectly and styles are loaded for page. But QWebView doesn't want to load styles via base tag, although with absolute paths to css files page is shown perfectly in QWebView.

My question is: is it possible to make base tag work in QWebView? Or maybe there is another way to obtain relative links to files that QWebView understands well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem was that QWebView doesn't add "file:///" to url, so it can be added in base tag before relative path. But more convenient choise is to set base url in setHtml function the same way as in base tag!

```
QUrl baseUrl("file:///d:/Server/styles/");
ui->webView->setHtml(textDocument->toPlainText(), baseUrl);
```